# Adding a second nested document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document with this structure

```
{
    name : "...",
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    hours : {
        standard : {
            ...
        }
}
```

I need to add:

```
{
    holiday : {
        ...
    }
}
```

inside the hours document and end up with:

```
{
    name : "...",
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    hours : {
        standard : {
            ...
        },
        holiday : {
            ...            
        }
    }
}
```

I tried running

```
{
    $set : {
        hours : {
            holiday : {
                ...            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that simply replaced my standard with holiday inside of hours.  How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
db.collection.update(query, {$set: {'hours.holiday': {...}}});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  (by the way this taught me the harsh lesson of why you test a query on a test db FIRST)

Comment: you should make backups also :)

Comment: I forgot I actually made one this morning.  I am in good shape :)  Thanks again.